# Should I create three models or a polymorphic type

Tags: laravel

I have a Laravel 8 application and am wondering how to solve the problem of how to solve a typical `polymorphic` issue. I have an `Employee` model. That Employee can be an `ExecutiveEmployee` or `EntryLevelEmployee`. There will be methods an `ExecutiveEmployee` has that an `EntryLevelEmployee` doesn't have and the inverse is also true.

Using Laravel 8, is it right to create a base `Employee` model (without a corresponding table?) and then create two models named `ExecutiveEmployee` and `EntryLevelEmployee` that inherit from `Employee`? This would also imply that both employee types will have two different database tables, even though there will be a lot of overlapping data.

Does it make sense to just have one `Employee` model and create a migration that has the employee type listed in the model? I am assuming that it's ok if an `EntryLevelEmployee` has some database attributes which are relevant to it that may or may not be relevant to an `ExecutiveEmployee` type here, or is that an incorrect assumption?

What's the correct way to model this in Laravel 8? I prefer to keep everything in one table because of how similar the models are. I do have to keep in mind that there will be data that one has that the other doesn't. There will be different accessor methods as well.

Is it possible to have everything in one `employees` table while utilizing multiple models? Meaning, if I create two models named `ExecutiveEmployee` and `EntryLevelEmployee` they would both query the underlying table `employees`?

**UPDATE 1**

The more I research, the more I think polymorphism is the incorrect approach here and what I might need is `Single-Table Inheritance`. [This package](https://github.com/calebporzio/parental) seems to bring the capability to Eloquent. Would there be a good reason to not use this?

Comment: Is there need for `ExecutiveEmployee` and `EntryLevevEmployee` be row in basic `users` table (if there is one)? Second question (or in other words) will every user (in case of `users` table) be one of a kind `[ExecutiveEmployee:class, EntryLevevEmployee:class]`?

Comment: @Tpojka Users are not Employee types.

Comment: I would go (I always tend to go with naming convention recommended by language/technology/technique/framework) `employeeable` table for polymorphic table. And also, there in that polymorphic pivot should be kept all mutual attributes. `ExecutiveEmployee` and `EntryLevelEmployee` can have their attributes and separate attribute child tables if needed. It's up to business logic if that should be 1:1, 1:n or m:n polymorph relation.

Comment: If you have 3-5 columns of specific data for each type of Employee, I don't see why not simplify it all and make only one `Employee` model. It is much easier to manage later on. But if there is a lot of different information about the two types, it's better to decouple it.

Comment: In my opinion, the point of using an ORM is to have an OOP "bridge" between a relational database and an OOP language so in that sense if it makes sense to have a base class for the two other classes (i.e. you want to define a base behaviour which the other classes will inherit) then it would be correct to create a base class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use polymorphic relationships in this case, because you are more flexible and have less coupling.

Using the `Single Table Inheritance (STI)`, you can add type specific columns in the `employees` table and make them `nullable`. But think about adding/removing types in the future.

```
executive_employees
    id - integer
    executive_specific - string

entry_level_employees
    id - integer
    entry_level_specific - string

employees
    id - integer
    name - string
    email - string
    employable_id - integer
    employable_type - string
```

As for the STI the same would be

```
employees
    id - integer
    name - string
    email - string
    type - string
    executive_specific - nullable string
    entry_level_specific - nullable string
```

So STI would be suitable when you don't have type specific columns. But you want to add specific behavior in your code. For example a User type (Admin, Author).

Even so, it's a matter of preferences.

Answer (score 1):

*It really depends on the state and behavior of your employee object.*

**Below are few points I will consider to make a decision**

- If your objects' states/properties are different then definitely you will create different models as your data will be stored in different tables.
- If most states/properties are same and some are different, you can
  consider storing all in one table/model and for the difference in
  behavior create separate table like [Ron Van Der Heijden](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64244202/5321614) has
  suggested and you can consider query scope with that to make
  transaction with database.

And another view will be

- How many JOINs you will create if you will create different tables,
  will that impact the performance and other stuffs, will it make your
  code complex?
- Can you make simpler relations and handle stuffs independently?
- When you are making an API, will your
  code make the api overworking? or you need to create too many request
  for any operation?

These stuffs will decide how you will make a decision.

**Update 1:**
Another point I would like to add about the package you are thinking to use, consider using a parent key in table and you can define relationships in a single model.I do not think you need to use a package, you can define it yourself, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you don't create a simple one-to-many relation. Based on the information you provided, the polymorphic relation looks unnecessary. I think the right way is to create employee_roles table and relations. Then you can give different permissions to different employee types. There are several ways to do that. You can create a middleware to create route restrictions. You can check the role before executing a function in the controller, and run only if the employee has permission. You can use if-else in blade not to render the parts that can't be used by auth user etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you have different “types” of employees, and each employee type should have different logic then yeah, that sounds like a polymorphic relationship.